# chosen jquery plugin: slidedown when hover

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I am using the [chosen jquery plugin](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). I would like to know how to slide the dropdown down on mouseover? (and of course slide it up on mouseout).

```
<div>
    <select name="type" id="select1">
        <option value="">Select Type</option>
        <option value="commercial">Commercial</option>
        <option value="condo">Condo</option>
        <option value="single-family">Single Family</option>
        <option value="townhouse">Townhouse</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/betteful/rt97wtqc/) for the extended form.

Comment: Hi do you want like this http://jsfiddle.net/firstuser/rt97wtqc/6/ ?

Comment: Ok i have edit the plugin please replace the chosen js with this one

Answer (score 2):

The hard part is that `jquery-chosen` doesn't load the option on the page load.. So just in case you can add the option on page load, then you can use something like this:

```
$(".chosen-container-single").hover(function(){
   $(this).addClass("chosen-with-drop");
   $(this).addClass("chosen-container-active");
},function(){
   $(this).removeClass("chosen-with-drop");
   $(this).removeClass("chosen-container-active");
});
```